# How can I use information from a PHP script in JavaScript from different files?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm fairly new to PHP and JavaScript, so I was wondering if it was possible to use info taken from a .php into a JavaScript variable and use it outside of the script itself. Here is the particular case I'm tackling right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>LaWeaaa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/login.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = pru.php>
        var img = '<?php echo $imagenes;?>'
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As it goes, I'd like to know if it is possible to use the variable 'img' outside of the script and if so, how to do it properly.

Comment: What do you mean, `outside of the script`? Since it's echoed into the `<script>`, you can have the Javascript use it as desired, including for manipulating HTML

Comment: The `src = pru.php` won't work. May we see that file (or a sample of it) in your question? Does it just contain data or does it run code (and set variables)?

Comment: You can just do echo it out like you do in the javascript.  <img src="<?php echo $imagenes;?>">

Comment: Think of PHP files as server-side scripts which output whole other files (like HTML or JS). For example, you could use something like: `<script type='text/javascript' src='myPhpFile.php'></script>` where myPhpFile.php can use whatever variables and output them however you want, and then return a valid JavaScript file to process when your HTML file is loaded in the browser.

Comment: @halfer pru is just a test .php, it only says <?php $imagenes = "genial"; ?> I just want to use the value of img in the body, not the script. Since I'm trying to show it in the same html page.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. First the PHP, arranged to return a value (or set of values):

```
<?php

return [
    'foo' => "genial",
    // Any other values here...
];
```

And the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = <?php echo json_encode(require('pru.php')) ?>,
        img  = data['foo'];
</script>
```

The `require()` fetches the data `return`ed by the script, and then the data is encoded in a string format that is native to JavaScript.

Of course, you can just return a bare string from the PHP script, but I've shown how to return an array, in case your actual needs are more complex.